# Migrate from HMC to Backoffice using the HMC Config Migrator tool

Tags: migration, sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I need to migrate HMC to Backoffice as we are upgrading the Hybris version in our project.

According to the SAP documentation this can be done using this tool: [HMC Config Migrator](https://help.sap.com/viewer/5c9ea0c629214e42b727bf08800d8dfa/6.5.0.0/en-US/461287cde3c345a0913c8318cadbe7cb.html)

I have downloaded the tool as a ZIP file and unzipped it:
[The unzipped hmc config migrator files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hhl9i.png)

In the SAP documentation there is no guide on how to run this tool so my question is:

**How do I start/run this [HMC Config Migrator tool](https://help.sap.com/viewer/5c9ea0c629214e42b727bf08800d8dfa/6.5.0.0/en-US/461287cde3c345a0913c8318cadbe7cb.html) after I've unzipped its files?**

Answer (score 1):

The tool is simply a Hybris extension that you can add to your project. Add the unzipped extension code to your custom folder as with any custom extension, then add an entry in your `localextensions.xml`.

Once you rebuild and restart server, it should appear in Backoffice as a new perspective that you can switch to in order to use the tool.